# How do I get my dwarfs inside?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I order everyone inside when I'm being attacked?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to define a [burrow](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Burrow) for the safe zone, and a civilian [alert](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Alerts) that restricts movement to it.

- To create the burrow

1. Press <kbd>w</kbd> to go to the burrows screen
2. Press <kbd>a</kbd> to add a new burrow
3. Size the burrow (remember, a  burrow is 3d)
4. Choose a name, color, etc

- To create a new alert

1. Press <kbd>m</kbd> to go to the military screen
2. Press <kbd>a</kbd> to go to the alerts screen
3. Press <kbd>c</kbd> to create a new alert
4. Name it with <kbd>N</kbd>
5. Now move the cursor to the far right column, which should have the burrow you just created, and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to associate that burrow with your new alert. You'll see a green A next to the burrow when you have that alert selected.

- To activate the alert (as the civilian alert)

1. Press <kbd>m</kbd> to go to the military screen
2. Press <kbd>a</kbd> to go to the alerts screen
3. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> while the alert is highlighted.

- To deactivate the alert

  1. Press <kbd>m</kbd> to go to the military screen
  2. Press <kbd>a</kbd> to go to the alerts screen
  3. Select the 'Inactive' alert state, and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

---

- See also:
- [Military Interface](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Military_interface)
- [Scheduling](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Scheduling)
- [Civilian Alert Guide](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/User:Khearn/CivilianAlertBurrow)

Comment: @C.Ross Thank you so much. I didn't notice this in Captnduck's tutorials, or 51ppycup's 2012 tutorials. How early in the game do you personally do this? Do you end up having to change the size of your burrow as your fortress grows, or do you just plan ahead for your whole fortress?

Comment: @theJollySin Happy to help.  I usually do it after the first wave of migrants, but you can set it all up on pause if you have to.  I usually do have to expand it, adding internal and external burrows and the like.